# Using In Memory Authentication and Database Authentication in same project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an existing project which is using InMemory authentication with Spring Security and now there is a new requirement. Now we also need to use Database based authentication along with the InMemory authentication, as there will be two types of users : one static and other dynamically added; for the dynamically added we need to use database based authentication. I have used both InMemory and Database based authentication in different projects but not both within same project.
Please suggest some solutions using both on same project. I am using Spring Boot 2.0.2Release and Java based solution is most welcome.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Value("${admin.username}")
    String user;

    @Value("${admin.password}")
    String password;

    @Value("${superadmin.username}")
    String admin;

    @Value("${superadmin.password}")
    String adminPassword;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","/blogs","/support","/index","/pricing","/step-guide","/sales-info","/sales-info/**","/step-guide/**","/blogs/**","/productdetail","/25-point-checklist-for-networking","/thanks-for-downloading-checklist","/events-&-conference",,"/share_profile","/share","/share/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN","ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()       
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                String currentUsername = authentication.getName();
                if(currentUsername.equals(admin)) {
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/admin");
                }
                else if(currentUsername.equals(user))
                {
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/swagger-ui.html");
                }
            }

        })
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();


    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()       
        .withUser(user)
        .password(PasswordUtil.encryptPassword(password))
        .credentialsExpired(false)
        .accountExpired(false)
        .accountLocked(false)       
        .roles("SUPER_ADMIN");

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(admin)
        .password(PasswordUtil.encryptPassword(adminPassword))
        .credentialsExpired(false)
        .accountExpired(false)
        .accountLocked(false)
        .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**","/webjars/**","/static/**","/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**","/favicon.ico","/swagger-resources/**","/bucket/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }   

}
```

And code with database authentication and custom authentication handler is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**","/webjars/**","/static/**","/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**","/favicon.ico");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/user/sign_up").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/user/forgot_password").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler).permitAll()     
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

So I want to combine these two, and it can have single login page or multiple login page depending upon case.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter you have this:

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {

         //   auth.ldapAuthentication()...
        auth.apply(new LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer());
        auth.apply(new JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<>());
        auth.apply(new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<>());
 }
```

Method ldapAuthentication() is doing nothing else than adding a LdapAuthenticationProvider to a config list of the AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.
Just try adding another Configurer to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder.

Example:

```
InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer memprovider = 
    new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer();

    memprovider.withUser("admin")
            .credentialsExpired(false)
            .accountExpired(false)
            .accountLocked(false)
            .roles("SUPER_ADMIN");
    auth.apply(memprovider);
```

This applys a new Provider. An than simply apply a second one:

```
JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer jdpbProvider = 
    new JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer();
    jdpbProvider.withUser("user").password() ...
    auth.apply(jdpbProvider);
```

With UserDetailService:

```
 @Autowired
 UserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;
```

and

```
 DaoAuthenticationConfigurer daoAC = 
     new DaoAuthenticationConfigurer(appUserDetailsService);
 daoAC.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
 auth.apply(daoAC);
```

Comment: I  added some infos to my answer. Maybe I do not understand you, but with this you can add two different types of auth. providers. You can remove the withUser in the JDBCProvider so is can be used for everyone.

Comment: And if I need to user custom implementation of UserDetailsServicea and custom authentication hander ? Also I am using Spring Data.

Comment: One question I have is, if someone logs in with static credentials and someone logs in with DB credentials, and with same login page ? Will it work ? If yes, then how Spring Security handles this, either to check static credentials or DB ?

Comment: When I follow above solution, it gives this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Comment: My answer is not an all-inclusive-answer-to-copy-and-paste-in-your-code. When you need a passwordEncoder within an AuthenticationConfigurer then add one. The JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer might not have a withUser() because it would not make sense.

Comment: I fixed it. I just used your DaoAuthenticationConfigurer and followed on my own. And continued my above code worked. Thank you for hint. And I didn't copy pasted. 

Comment: I am pleased to hear that :-) Would be nice if you mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` in Spring security and use Database and InMemory as `providers`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

Following setup should work on your case:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuth.setUserDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
        daoAuth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuth);

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()       
        .withUser(user)
        .password(PasswordUtil.encryptPassword(password))
        .credentialsExpired(false)
        .accountExpired(false)
        .accountLocked(false)       
        .roles("SUPER_ADMIN");

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(admin)
        .password(PasswordUtil.encryptPassword(adminPassword))
        .credentialsExpired(false)
        .accountExpired(false)
        .accountLocked(false)
        .roles("ADMIN");
    }
```

Comment: It is recommended also to add an explanation to your code.